# If $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ then what is $\mathcal{R}(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I am given the prompt: suppose $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$  and $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ where $b \in \mathcal{R}(A)$...

But I have not seen this $\mathcal{R}$ before. Normally I have seen it maybe used in the context of complex numbers to represent the real term of a complex number, but this context sets the vector and matrix to being real.

What does his *function* $\mathcal{R}$ do to $A$ in $\mathcal{R}(A)$?

**EDIT**

Thanks to Arturo Magidin, I looked in the back of my book to see that this means the range of matrix $A$.

Comment: “I am given the prompt”... well, whoever gave you the prompt is supposed to give you the notation. Ask them. If it’s a book, then check the symbol index.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @copper.hat yes

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Thank you, found it in the back